# D3.js v4 circle radius transition not working as expected

Tags: javascript, transition, d3.js

Using D3.js v4, I'm trying to update the radius of a circle on button click.

The problem is that, instead of [smooth transitions between the radii](http://bl.ocks.org/benjchristensen/1473535) the circle is redrawn (going from 'radius1' to 0 and only then to 'radius2') upon each update.

Here's the complete code:
https://jsfiddle.net/4r6hp9my/

Here's the circle update code snippet:

```
        var circles = svg.selectAll('circle').data(dataset);

        var enter = circles
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attrs({
            cx: w/2,
            cy: h/2,
            fill: colorsScale,
            r: function(d,i){
                if(i == myCounter){
                    var x = rScale(d)
                return x; 
                }
            }
        });

        d3.select('#theButton')
            .on('click',function(){ 
                myCounter++
                 if(myCounter == dataset.length){
                    myCounter = 0;
                };
                updateData()
            });

        function updateData(){ 
            circles
            .merge(enter)
            .transition()
            .attr('r',function(d,i){
                if(i == myCounter){
                    return rScale(d);
                }
            });
            labels
            .text(function(d,i){
                if(i == myCounter){
                return d;
                }   
            });

        };
```

Comment: How many circles you think there are when you first open the fiddle?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, there's supposed to be only one circle, whose radius gets updated (based on values in a one dimensional array) with every button click

Comment: :) Open your inspector and look inside your svg element.You've appended 9 circles to your svg. That is, 1 for each of your `dataset` elements.

Comment: What I mean is; you are updating each of these circles' radius with each click. Each of them is having their radius transitioned from none to the value in the dataset. That's why it's animation is like creating a new circle with each click.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by echonax, the issue is you're creating multiple circles based on the dataset.  To get the smooth transition, draw only one circle, and update the radius based on 'myCounter'.  An example:

```js
var dataset = [2184,2184,3460,2610,2610,2452,842,1349,2430];

var myCounter = 0;
//svg dimensions
var h = 200;
var w = 200;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attrs({
  width: w,
  height: h
})
.classed('middle',true);
//color mapping
var colorsScale = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([d3.min(dataset),d3.max(dataset)])
.range(['#FFB832','#C61C6F']);
//radius mapping
var rScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, d3.max(dataset)]).range([0,50])
//labels
var label = svg.append("text").attrs({
  x: w/2,
  y: 20
}).text(function(){ return dataset[myCounter] });

//draw the circles
var circle = svg.append('circle')
.attrs({
    cx: w/2,
    cy: h/2,
    fill: function() { return colorsScale(dataset[myCounter]) },
    r: function() { return rScale(dataset[myCounter]) }
});
//button click
d3.select('#theButton')
  .on('click',function(){ 
  updateData()
});

function updateData(){
 myCounter++;
  if ( myCounter > dataset.length - 1 ) myCounter = 0;
  circle.transition().attr('r',function(){ return rScale(dataset[myCounter]) }).attr('fill', function() { return colorsScale(dataset[myCounter]) });
  label.text(function(){ return dataset[myCounter] });
};
```

```css
html, body{
 height: 100%;
}

.middle{
 margin: 100px auto;
}

#theButton{
 position: absolute;
 left:50px;
 top:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
        
<button id="theButton" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Based on your data, there are a couple of times that the circle won't change as the data is the same, but the transition should work when it does.

Comment: Didn't even realise I'd put that in there!  Removed.